# jquery e.preventDefault stops loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I have problem with the following code :

```
function KeyCheck(e) {

            // ... Some Code

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        width = elements[i].offsetWidth;

        if(width > 245) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }   
}
```

As you can see I have a loop, I want only elements that are less than 245px to
have the event work, and the elements that are bigger than 245px not have it work.

The Problem - When the if 'meets' an element with width less than 245px it stops the loop and I think it exits the function also...

What can I do so it will continue looping and only elements less than 245px wide will get the event to work ?

Comment: Not enough info available. How are `elements` and `length` defined?

Comment: @Shmiddty those variables are pretty complicated but the elements[i] it is a array of divs, and the length it is just elements.length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?: http://jsfiddle.net/D2xhz/

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if ($(this).width() > 245)
        e.preventDefault();
});​
```

The bottom two inputs cannot be typed in.

Comment: Thanks man!! It works, You did the same thing that I did but in jQuery, e.preventDefault(); works only in jQuery event functions?

Comment: Not exactly. `preventDefault` isn't standard across all browsers, but jQuery will create it when it isn't there.

Answer (score 4):

The code as-is will continue looping until the end of the loop unless `preventDefault` is not defined on `e`

Comment: I added this line of code if (e && e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } but it is still doesn't work... It looks like when that command is fired it is preventing the event to work on any of the elements that comes with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault(); should use in event callback function to set aside you defaul event i.e form submiting.

I your case you should execute some action for div small 145px